# Case When formula to COUNT on results tab

Tags: sql, netsuite

On results tab of saved search, I would like to display a `COUNT` of Opportunities that do not have SLX in Title, Memo or Item Name. I'm using a transaction saved search.

I have tried a formula(numeric)results column and it returns incorrect results of one per grouped rep:

```
Formula(Numeric) Summary type: COUNT
CASE WHEN({title} = 'SLX') Or ({memo} = 'SLX') Or ({item.name} = 'SLX') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Counts one per Rep (grouped).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think `sum()` is more appropriate:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN({title} = 'SLX') Or ({memo} = 'SLX') Or ({item.name} = 'SLX') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Your expression is equivalent to `COUNT(*)`, because `COUNT()` counts non-NULL values and all the values are either `1` or `0`.

Comment: You could also just remove the `ELSE 0` from your formula so that unmatched records are null